# Polygon not being drawn on Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, polygon

I am learning WPF and trying to dynamically draw a collection of polygons to a canvas.

I am configuring the polygons as follows:

```
mHexagon = new Polygon();
mHexagon.Width = Diameter * 2;
mHexagon.Height = Diameter * 2;
mHexagon.StrokeThickness = 1;
mHexagon.Stroke = Brushes.AliceBlue;
mHexagon.Points = new PointCollection(Vertices.Select(v => new Point(v.X, v.Y)));
```

Sample point collection:

> Vertices
>       :128,64
>       :96,8.57437415779593
>       :32,8.57437415779592
>       :0,64
>     :32,119.425625842204
>       :96,119.425625842204

I am adding the polygon as follows (encapsulated in `Hexagon` class):

```
PlayerMapWindow.Children.Add(hex.Polygon);
```

And my XAML looks like:

```
<Border BorderThickness="1"
        BorderBrush="DarkRed"
        Background="Black"
        Padding="2">
    <Viewbox Name="PlayerMapViewbox" 
             VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Canvas Name="PlayerMapWindow"/>
    </Viewbox>
</Border>
```

After adding the polygon (hex) to the canvas children, nothing is drawn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the **`ViewBox`** and your code works fine.

```
<Border BorderThickness="1"
        BorderBrush="DarkRed"
        Background="Black"
        Padding="2">
   <Canvas Name="PlayerMapWindow"/>
</Border>
```

---

Canvas has **default height and width set to 0**. If you want scaling feature of ViewBox, you have to constraint width and height of canvas.

```
<Border BorderThickness="1"
        BorderBrush="DarkRed"
        Background="Black"
        Padding="2">
    <Viewbox Name="PlayerMapViewbox" 
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Canvas Name="PlayerMapWindow" Width="300" Height="300"/>
    </Viewbox>
</Border>
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.aspx):

> Canvas is the only panel element that has no inherent layout
>   characteristics. A Canvas has **default Height and Width properties of
>   zero**, unless it is the child of an element that automatically sizes
>   its child elements. Child elements of a Canvas are never resized, they
>   are just positioned at their designated coordinates. This provides
>   flexibility for situations in which inherent sizing constraints or
>   alignment are not needed or wanted. For cases in which you want child
>   content to be automatically resized and aligned, it is usually best to
>   use a Grid element.

Comment: I thought the `ViewBox` would be necessary for when a canvas ends up being large enough to require scroll bars.

Comment: Okay, this looks promising. I've got another question I'll be posting about the placement of dynamically drawn polygons. This is a fun challenge.